# What's the problem(s) with overriding a method with different access in base vs derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, private, public, protected

PC-Lint issues a warning when a method is overriden in a derived class with access specifier other than what is the inherited access. For example

```
class B {
public:
    virtual void fubar(void);
};

class D : public B {
private:
    virtual void fubar(void);
};
```

One explaination I've seen is that the above would violate the Liskov Substitution Principle, but that's only case where the derived class has stricter access (like the example above), right? I'm also noting that here's a backdoor to D::fubar since we can cast a reference/pointer to D to reference/pointer to B and then we can call D::fubar since it's virtual. Is there any other problems?

What about if the derived class has looser access? For example:

```
class B {
protected:
    virtual void fubar(void);
};

class D : public B {
public:
    virtual void fubar(void);
};
```

Is there any problems associated with this type of override?

Comment: "but that's only case where the derived class has stricter access, right?" - which your derived class *has* - base "public", derived "private". Also; don't always take linter warnings as gospel truth - there are sometimes good reasons to ignore them (even if they are often right for the general case).

Comment: @JesperJuhl Yes, that's the first example. The second example has the base is protected and derived public.

Comment: It just seems like something that is in most cases unintentional. What reasons would you have to e.g. disallow someone to call `fubar` on a `D`, but allow them to cast to a `B` reference/pointer first and then call it? Both operations have the same effect if they are allowed.

Comment: The point of making a function `virtual` is to be able to call the dynamic type implementation through a base pointer. What's the advantage of increasing its visibility in a child class?

Comment: The problem with the first example is that `D d; d.fubar();` will not compile if the code doing that is neither a `friend` nor a member of `D`,  but `D d; B &b = d; b.fubar();` will compile, and call `D`s private member.   That will generally be counter-intuitive and/or a design error - why should code that has access to a pointer/reference to `B` be able to call `D`s private member, but not do that directly to a `D`?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing inherently wrong with changing the access type. The language allows it.
It is just that it is probable an error to change it, as the base class designer already decided what access should that method have.

If you make it stricter, it really doesn't matter, as any pointer to the base class will be able to call it, so this one is almost always an error.

If you make it less strict, it might expose a design issue, so this should be considered also a probable error.

One possible use case, would be if you don't own the base class (i.e. it is a external library or something). You may use this to directly expose some functionality, but again, this should be treated with caution.

About your "backdoor" access, note that the access specifiers are meant for "correct" usage of the language and diagnosting errors, not against malevolent usage.
There are some lines of thought about always treating protected methods as if they were public (or even not using protected at all), just because they can be published at any time....

And finally, note that override has nothing to do with access type. You could do the following, and it would work as expected:

```
struct Base {
private:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct Derived: public Base {
private:
    void foo() override;
};
```

[Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/E6Txo7K8W)

In this snippet, only `Base` functions can call `foo()`, but they will call the overriden function in `Derived`. Note that being private, derived implementations cannot call `Base::foo()`, so it is a pattern usually used with pure virtual functions.

Comment: Why is it an LSP violation when you change access specifier to less strict? I'm genuinly curious, to me it seems no different than adding a method to a child class that wasn't present in the base class.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen because if you rely on that method outside your hierarchy, then you cannot change it with a sibling type, as the other type might not have that method accessible.

Comment: oh sorry. Facepalm. I simply forgot to write a definition of the method anywhere.

Comment: @LoPiTaL I don't really get that about LSP. If D1 and D2 are subtypes of B then as I understand it you should be able to replace B with D1 or D2, but no requirement that you should be able to replace D1 with D2?

Comment: @skyking you are right. I have removed that part.